# Element is already the child of another element, Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, class, windows-phone-8, parent-child, observablecollection

Hey embarrassingly enough I ran into the error stated in the title. As many others have sought to find a solution online, but I was not able to do so.

Okay so my issue, is that I have an ObservableCollection of my elements which is used in an Itemscontrol. I want to create a new element of one of the elements in the ObservableCollection. Because of the trouble with working with ObservableCollection I created a serializing and Deserializing of the specific object. like this>

```
IsolatedStorage.SerializeSElement("saveString", saveElement);
IsolatedStorage.DeSerializeSElement("saveString", loadElement);
```

Which I than hoped gave me a completely new element. But I still have the same element. How do I solve the issue if say my class looks like>

```
public class myElement(){
    int posx;
    int posy;
    double id;
    bool isMoveable;
}
```

But there is still the error, is there way to solve this error?

**Code**

```
 private Geometry createGeometry(SViewModel sModelRec)
        {//TEST

            sModel = sModelRec.Gear;
            sModelRec = null;
            //new Path.Combine(DecorationOnShield[i].Gear.Path,"");
            PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
            PathFigure testPathFigure = new PathFigure();

            System.Windows.Shapes.Path pathTesting = new System.Windows.Shapes.Path();
            var b = new System.Windows.Data.Binding
            {
                Source = sModel.Path
            };

            System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations.SetBinding(pathTesting, System.Windows.Shapes.Path.DataProperty, b);
            pathTesting.Width = sModel.Width;
            pathTesting.Height = sModel.Height;

            Geometry geometry = pathTesting.Data;
            return geometry;
        }
```

So when I return the element and add it to the GeometryGroup I get the error.

Comment: which part of code throwing that "*Element is already the child of another element*" exception? If it is when you call your custom function, you should post the function definition as well

Comment: @har07 No it is not there. Maybe I was unclear. I introduced those to try and solve the issue. They work fine, and save the element to isolated storage. No I am creating a Geometry element, that I add to a geometryGroup, and when I add it to the geometryGroup the exception is fired. So when I am creating the geometry in Code from the item in the ObservablCollection, I get the error.

Comment: What type is this `sModel.Path`

Comment: sModel is my own type. But it is basiclly the model to a usercontrol. Consisting of ints and doubles for positioning and sizing.

Comment: I mean the property `Path` not `sModel`

Comment: it is a string that I bind to a path in a usercontrol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to Add a Control and that Control already exists in your VisualTree.
The solution is simple

You have **Source Parent Container** = The control in witch resides the element you want to add to the other container
         **Target Parent Container** = The control in witch you want to add your element.

To solve your problem just remove the element from the Source Parent Container and then add it to your Target Parent Container

**Note**: to have an answer more specific to your situation you must post your view or the lines where the error is getting thrown

Comment: I am sorry it is not another control in XAML, it is one in the code a GeometryGroup. It is not possible to create a copy of a class I added in the question, without deleting the existing element?

Comment: Maybe you didn't add it to any control but through the code is automatically associated to some control

Comment: So I tried this, and also tried accessing the UIElement stack in the itemscontrol. But still an issue. I think it is because I have it in an observable collection. But How do you make a new element of this if serializing does not work? Can you extract the individual values without getting this error?

Comment: It appears to me that you are returning the same object `Source = sModel.Path` I don't know if the `SViewModel` that you pass to the method is always the same. If so there is a problem with that.

Comment: The sviewmodel, is allways a new one as it is a list I am going through and sending one element to this function. And return the geometry element. But when I return the geometry element I get the error :S so something in the geometry element is a child of another. Which must be the sModel.path, which comes from the sViewModel. But if that is the case I cannot see how to circumvent the problem as I try to create new elements, and try to serialize them. 
If you have an element in an observableCollection How would you pull out information from that collection without getting the error?